# I use angular router and can't use path:'**' for 404 page

Tags: angular

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
  {
    path: '',
    component: FullComponent,
    canLoad: [LoginGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('./material-component/material.module').then(m => m.MaterialComponentsModule)
      },
      {path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: () => import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)}
    ]
  },
  {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];
```

but 404 page can only match:   '/a' '/b'      can't match:       '/a/b' '/c/d'

I think the '' url is not correct with **childen:**

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with

```
{ path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
```

Comment: actually I solved the problem , its not about route , my  index.html include <base href='./'> that cause the error , I should  change to <base href="/">    , thanks for your answer . hh

Answer (score 0):

You're right the problem is that.Your code should look  like this .

```
{
    path: 'material',
    loadChildren: () => import('./material-component/material.module').then(m => m.MaterialComponentsModule)
  },
```

**And in the MaterialComponentRountingModule**

```
{
    path: '',
    component:MaterialComponent
  },
```

Comment: actually I solved the problem , its not about route , my  index.html include <base href='./'> that cause the error , I should  change to <base href="/">    , thanks for your answer . hh